# Recognizer Intent is behaving differently on jellybeans and lollipop

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Here is my code.

```
speakButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition");
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH),0);
        if(activities.size() == 0){
            speakButton.setEnabled(false);
            speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
        }
```

Its running differently on different devices. Its working fine on lollipop but on jellybeans its showing "Recognizer not present".

Thank you

Comment: On the Jellybean device, is there a speech recognition engine installed?

Comment: @brandall , i had installed listNote speech to text. And no such app is installed on lollipop device

Comment: Check out this answer as I don't think the device is configured correctly http://stackoverflow.com/a/37876958/1256219