# Is possible voice recognition in Epson bt 300? E/SpeechRecognizer: no selected voice recognition service

Tags: android, speech-to-text, voice-recognition, epson

I am trying to develop a module in epson bt 300 based on voice recognition.

I implements the class: `RecognitionListener`, this is my code:

```
public class VoiceRecognitionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    RecognitionListener {

private static final int REQUEST_RECORD_PERMISSION = 1000;
private TextView returnedText;
private ToggleButton toggleButton;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private SpeechRecognizer speech = null;
private Intent recognizerIntent;
private String LOG_TAG = "VoiceRecognitionActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.voice_recognition_activity);
    speech = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);

    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "isRecognitionAvailable: " + SpeechRecognizer.isRecognitionAvailable(this));
```

And the result is this:

> E/SpeechRecognizer: no selected voice recognition service

Does anyone know the motive? Can voice recognition be implemented in epson bt 300?

The current version is: Android 5.1

Comment: Do you have a recognition service installed?  If not, install one.  Usually you can via the system menu.  If not, there should be something on the play store somewhere.

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37876958/1256219